# Access Token for php facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook API v2.4 to get updates of my fb and show it in my site. Having trouble with getting access token. As gone through the the [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens), what I need is a ***App Access Token***.

As suggested in the documentation I tried making a *GET* call to */oauth/access_token*. This returns me 
*Facebook\FacebookResponse* object. And using the access token in it I tried making a call to get `/me`

```
$response = $facebook->get('/me? access_token='.$accessToken);
```

This returns the below error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message 'An
>   active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException.php
>   on line 125

Using the same token that I used above, I am able to get response in [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). 
Why am I not able to use the same (App)token from my PHP? What am I missing?

Comment: You can not use `/me` in combination with an app access token – the only way the API knows who “me” is supposed to be, is via the access token; and therefor it works with user or page access tokens only. Use the id of the user profile or page(?) instead.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe So, is there a possibility to get access token programmatically, without user interaction?

Comment: No, getting a user or page access token requires user interaction. You can extend their validity period though, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: @CBroe . Thank you.. put ur reply as answer rather than comments. It helped me. The answer deserve rewards..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `/me` in combination with an app access token – the only way the API knows who “me” is supposed to be, is via the access token; and therefor it works with user or page access tokens only. Use the id of the user profile or page(?) instead.

And getting a user or page access token requires user interaction. You can extend their validity period though, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending